# Is it a good enough reason not to upgrade hardware because we are using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Our organisation will not upgrade our hardware because they believe that VS2010 with Resharper + other add-ins contribute to memory issues and performance-related issues that would not be resolved by hardware upgrades.

Our machines vary, but the highest spec machine we have is an i5 Laptop with 3Gb RAM running Windows XP 32-bit.  Security policies prevent us from disabling our On-Access virus-checking for *any* of our processes which means day-to-day running of VS2010 plus all the other associated services etc. means that life is slow.

We asked for new hardware recently because generally our machines do not run fast enough, so we want more RAM and SSD drives.  After weeks of investigation we were told that new hardware would only mask the underlying issue which lies with VS2010 and potential bugs that would be causing our performance issues?

Does anyone agree that new hardware is not the answer here?  Is it not that perhaps VS2010 is not running in its comfort zone?

Comment: Maybe upgrading to Windows 7 64 bit might help for a start? If you have Visual Studio 2010, odds are you have an MSDN subscription which means that licensing wouldn't be an issue?

Comment: We tried Windows 7 on a dual-core desktop with 6Gb RAM and it runs quite poorly, and I feel that a lot of that is attributed to hard disk and virus-scanning.

Comment: Hmm, I can't say in regards to the virus scanning but turning off indexing on W7 may help with the load on the hard drive? Apart from that the specs seem more than sufficient (I'm running well on less)!

Comment: The virus scanning is a hog, we managed to get them to turn it off for a bit and got a 30% increase, but if they aren't willing to turn that off then surely faster hardware is the only other option...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The honest answer is that they didn't want to buy new hardware and were looking for a reason to not.

The more complicated answer is that tests would need to be run to see where the performance bottlenecks are, that information is what will tell you what is causing the performance issue.

The simplest way is just to check the HDD light and monitor the CPU. If you notice that the CPU is always pegged then your issue is that you need a faster CPU. If you notice that your HDD is always busy then there are 2 options. 1. You are accessing a lot of files and the HDD is slowing you down or 2. You are constantly hitting the disk for paging, in which case more memory might help.

More than likely it's a combination of these issues, and a hardware upgrade would help, but you would need some numbers to determine how much it would help and in what areas it would help to be able to present a business case for this.

Even with all that most likely they still won't upgrade your hardware unless you can get a manager higher up to push them. This really comes down to finances more than anything.

Comment: Your last sentence just hit a nerve :-)  I've spent several days trying to benchmark on a test machine which amounts to between £1,200-£1,500 of chargeable cost of my time, 2 reasonably spec'd machines could've been purchased ;-)

Comment: I've been in similar kinds of situation in the past when management didn't upgrade machines very often.  The best way to make your case is to make a rough estimate of how many compile/execute cycles you do per day, and how long on average each one takes, compared with how many more cycles you could do per day on newer hardware.  Last time I did that calculation I found that a new PC would pay for itself in 3 weeks.

Comment: @the_mandrill, that's an excellent solution.  My only issue is how to measure how long it would take to compile on the newer hardware?

Comment: Well, that's harder to gauge unless you have temporary access to a faster machine to measure it, unfortunately. Still, even with a guess (eg 4 minute link reduced to 2 minutes) you can produce some example numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I think newer faster hard drives would greatly increase the speed of things.  I use VS2010 and Resharper on an i7 laptop and have times where it is very slow.  By using Process Explorer I can see that Visual Studio is reading the hard drive during slow times often at 10MB/sec+.  I believe the real culprit here is Resharper and it caching/processing in the background so its Intellisense is up to date.  The slow down seems to be even worse with large C++ projects.

You may want to use Process Explorer and prove that at times when the machine is slow there is a lot of disk activity.  Then focus your efforts on getting SSD hard drives.  Or RAID standard hard drives, if available in your laptop. I think an i5 with 3GB of RAM is fine and upgrading it wouldn't provide as much benefit as SSD.

Of course this is all just my opinion.